# jquery ajax post file , multiple files and text input

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, text, send

hello guys my html code :

```
<form action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="name" id=""><br>
   <input type="file" name="poster" id="poster"><br>
   <input type="file" name="scene[]" id="scene" multiple><br>
   <input type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

as you see a single file, multiple files, and I have one text value. This value 'ajax' with want to send at a time. 'JQuery' I use.

I can not run in any way

```
$(function(){
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var file_data = $('#poster').prop('files')[0];
            var form = $('form').serialize();
            var form_data = new FormData();
            $.each($('input[name="scene[]"]'),function(i, obj) {
                $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
                    form_data.append('photo['+i+']', file);
                    })
                });
            form_data.append(form);
            form_data.append('file',file_data);
            alert(form_data);
            $.ajax({
                url:'post.php',
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                async:false,
                data:form_data,
                type:'post',
                success:function(answ){
                    $('#result').html(answ);
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

I looked at other similar solutions, but it did not fix my problem
and sory my bad english .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this manually; if you just provide the `form` as a DOMElement to the `FormData` constructor then all the form values will be automatically included for you.

Also note that you should hook to the `submit` event of the form, not the `click` event of the submit button. You should also remove the use of `async: false` as it is incredibly bad practice to use.

With all that said, try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData(this); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(answ){
            $('#result').html(answ);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: ty very much . new FormData(this); I did not think about it. omg

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For your reference, here's the [FormData entry at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, this creates form's name-value pair using elements' name attribute. I am using ASP.NET which messes up elements' name for server side controls. Therefore, I use elements' IDs to construct name-value pairs using a serialize function (looping thru all form controls by id). Is there a way I can serialize for text controls and append file data to the formdata? I am OK to do it manually as OP was trying to do. Thanks in advance!